# Как определить кодировку файла?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, строки, кодировка

Sorry for my bad english.
I try to read the file with german umlauts in unknown code page. Here the lines, that i copied from notepad++ that encoding them in ANSI (?) code page:

```
4 CITY Mиunchen    
1 NAME иozkan/MиuLLER/
```

The client say that file in ANSEL (? but what) code page.
I need to encode/decode them from/into CString. I use my own functions in MFC application:

```
    enum ECodePage {E_CP_ANSEL = 1250, E_CP_UTF8 = CP_UTF8, E_CP_ASCII = 20127,
 E_CP_UNKNOWN = FAIL, E_CP_NONE = NONE};

CString FilestringToCString(string str, ECodePage ecp) {
    if (str.empty())
        return STR_EMPTY;

    int nSizeNeed = MultiByteToWideChar(ecp, 0, &str[0],-1,NULL,0);
    wstring strFrom(nSizeNeed,0);
    MultiByteToWideChar(ecp, 0, &str[0],(int)str.size(),&strFrom[0],nSizeNeed);

    return strFrom.c_str();
}

string CStringToFilestring(CString str, ECodePage ecp) {
    if (str.IsEmpty())
        return STRING_EMPTY;

    int nSizeNeed = WideCharToMultiByte(ecp, 0, str,-1, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    string strTo(nSizeNeed, 0);
    WideCharToMultiByte(ecp, 0, str,str.GetLength(),
        &strTo[0], nSizeNeed, NULL, NULL);

    return strTo;
}
```

CP_UTF8 - standard code page. Other code pages i take from
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx
I know that my code pages is 1250, 65001, 20127. And i named them **ANSEL**, **UTF-8**, **ASCII** respectively. It exactly and works well.
But client have its own files in ANSEL, ANSI, ASCII, WINDOWS and etc code pages.
Client **ANSI** - i read like my **ANSEL** - works well.
Client **WINDOWS** - read like **ANSEL** - works well.
Client **ANSEL** (file above) - i can't read (umlauts are down) in my code pages 1250 (ANSEL), 65001 (UTF-8), 20127 (ASCII).
I also tried read file like 1200, 12000, 65000 . I tried to find it code page online but it didn't work. Also i tried to read file in notepad++ code pages and total commander Lister code pages - didn't work. I can't read this umlauts.
How find exactly code page of this file?
Can anybody help please?

Comment: Извините, но это **русскоязычный** форум. 

Вопросы на English, возможно будет уместней задавать на похожем форуме -- `Stack Overflow`.

Comment: You cannot safely determine the encoding from the text file. You need to know in advance which the encoding is, and proceed accordingly.

Comment: @VladD, вообще можно, я узнал недавно, что в начале файла есть 2-3 символа, отвечающие за кодировку, они находятся в невидимом диапазоне. Их можно увидеть в шестнадцатеричном редакторе, например, в Lister total commander'а. Но этих символов в том файле нет, чтоб можно было судить хотя бы о битой кодировке. В любом случае я согласен с тобой, что невозможно заранее определить кодировку. Но и быстро подобрать её я не смог. Может, есть какой-то быстрый переключатель по всем возможным кодировкам, как рация для радиостанций. Но я уже использовал и в онлайне и 2 пс программы - не нашел.

Comment: @vityo, говоря о символах, отвечающих за кодировку, Вы имеете в виду [BOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)?

Он присутствует далеко не всегда и относится только к utf, хотя проверять его наличие не мешает в любом случае (например, чтобы не сбрабатывать его как часть данных).

Программы, определяющие (угадывающие) кодировки, есть. Обычно в них используется анализ статистики языка (сам писал).

Comment: Что же касается Вашего конкретного вопроса о кодировке клиента, то не могли бы Вы в дополнение к приведенному текстовому фрагменту

    4 CITY Mиunchen    
    1 NAME иozkan/MиuLLER/

выложить тот же кусок файла в hex.

Comment: @vityo: По поводу BOM, присоединяюсь к комментарию @avp. Он является de facto-стандартом на Windows-платформе, но не на Linux, и относится лишь к UTF-кодировкам. Различить однобайтные кодировки он вам не поможет.

Ну и, конечно, можно пытаться угадать кодовую страницу на основе частотного анализа. Но для случая, когда у вас всё ASCII, и только 2-3 символа выходят за эти рамки, вероятность успеха невелика.

Comment: @avp, в hex: "Mиunchen иozkan/MиuLLER/" - " "4D E8 75 6E 63 68 65 6E 20 E8 6F 7A 6B 61 6E 2F 4D E8 75 4C 4C 45 52 2F"
___
http://www.oszk.hu/karaktertabla
На этой странице я наконец нашел умлауты в Hex кодировке, это e86f o-umlaut и e875 u-umlaut. И там написано, что это ANSEL кодировка, но какой у неё точный код, неизвестно.
____
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSEL#GEDCOM
Это точно она вот на этой странице, т.е. это точно не ошибка клиента. Допустим, её точное название с этой страницы - ANSEL (ANSI/NISO Z39.47-1985). Надо подумать, как мне именно по ней прочитать файл.